# OutputCache being invalidated

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've noticed that every time we alter the response cookies through:

```
HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie)
```

Header becomes:

```
Cache-Control: public, no-cache="Set-Cookie"
```

and Output Cache is invalidated.

It is very annoying and I was wondering if any one noticed similiar issues while output caching.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, if you add a cookie to the response, don't you expect the browser to read it and then post it back on the next request? If the page is cached by the browser that cannot happen. So, it makes sense to invalidate the cache if a cookie is added to the response. It would be far more annoying if your cookie disappeared because the browser never got it.

Comment: Honestly I was expecting to have more control over output cache while writing cookies - like various VaryBy* options. Yes it makes sense to invalidate the cache after the cookie write but I just have the case that this should not happen and I was wondering if there is some clean way to prevent it.

Answer (score 1):

You could always switch to using a server-side caching model, such as [`System.Web.Caching.Cache`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [`System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which would share caching of objects between users while still allowing communication with the browser.

Frankly, this server-side is the first caching model I have used. I only recently started using output caching and I find it very limited by comparison. Its only advantages are that it caches the page on the client side under certain scenarios and that it caches content rather than the data that generates the content (saving some CPU cycles). Its main disadvantage is that you *have to* disable it under certain conditions, such as during authentication or writing cookies. You never have to disable server-side caching - not even for application pool recycles - because it doesn't hinder communication with the browser.

For the best of both worlds, you could combine both approaches so whatever backend process that you don't want executed multiple times provide cached data when the view is generated. Then you would have client-side caching in most cases, and would rely on the server side caching when updating cookies. It could take more memory to use this approach, but that tradeoff might be worth it in your case.

Comment: Thanks for the input. That was the solution that we've thought about as well but on the other side we would like to stay on OutputCache that is build in framework.